# Coordination of Metadata and Data Fetching in Next.js App Router

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, swr

I am pulling blog post content using **SWR** and then updating the page's title according to the title I receive from the **API**. Which requires a client component. So, I have moved my data-fetching part to a component named `Content` to make `Page` component a server component. But the problem was not solved because I had to use the `useSate()` hook to pull title data from the child component name `Content`.

The problem is, I can not update `metadata` or `generateMetadata()` in the client component but without a client component, I can not get the title data. How to solve this?

**Note:** I did try `document.title = title;` and it works fine. But I have to use `metadata` or `generateMetadata()` for the same problem since the problem should be solved using the framework's default solution or tools.

#### Source of the `@/app/[slug]/page.tsx`

```
'use client'

import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { useState } from 'react';
import Content from '@/app/[slug]/content'

const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: 'Loading ...',
    description: '...',
};

export default function Page({ params }: { params: { slug: string } }) {
    const [ postTitle, setPostTitle ] = useState<string>('Loading ...');

    const changeTitle = (title: string) => {
       setPostTitle(title);
       console.log('Found from child: ' + title); // Working fine by showing the title in the console

       // I can use "document.title = title;" here; but I have to use default metadata of Next.js
    };

    return <Content slug={ params.slug } onTitleReceived={ changeTitle }/>;
};
```

#### Source of the `@/app/[slug]/content.tsx`

```
import useSWR from 'swr'

const fetcher = async (url: RequestInfo | URL): Promise<any> => {
    try {
       const response: Response = await fetch(url);
       return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
       throw new Error('Error fetching data');
    }
};

export default function Content({ slug, onTitleReceived }: any): JSX.Element {
    const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR('API/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=' + slug, fetcher, {
       revalidateIfStale: false,
       revalidateOnFocus: false,
       revalidateOnReconnect: false
    });

    if (error) {
       return (
          <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col justify-between p-24">
             <div className="container mx-auto p-4">
                <h1 className="text-6xl font-bold text-center text-gray-800 dark:text-white">Error</h1>
                <p className="text-center text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Error: { error }</p>
             </div>
          </main>
       );
    }

    if (isLoading) {
       return (<main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col justify-between p-24">
          <div className="container mx-auto p-4">
             <h1 className="text-6xl font-bold text-center text-gray-800 dark:text-white">Loading</h1>
             <p className="text-center text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Data is loading .....</p>
          </div>
       </main>);
    }

    onTitleReceived(data[0].title.rendered);

    return (
       <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col justify-between p-24">
          <div className="container mx-auto p-4">
             <h1 className="text-6xl font-bold text-center text-gray-800 dark:text-white">{ data[0].title.rendered }</h1>
          </div>
          <div
             className="mx-32 mb-32">
             <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: data[0].content.rendered } }/>
          </div>
       </main>
    );
};
```